# Link between finite measure spaces and bounded metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure

I was taking a look at some measure theory, and, finding the concept of *finite measure space* I thought about the following question:

> *Is there some sort of a conceptual link (in the form of theories or specific theorems) between **finite measure spaces** and **bounded metric spaces**?*

Now, I am not completely sure this question makes sense, but I was lead to it by the potential analogy that there can be between the original *problem of measure* and the idea of distance between points as measured in some way.

Any feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Any metric space is equivalent to a bounded one (if $d$ is the metric, let $d'(x,y) = d(x,y)/(1+d(x,y))$). So I doubt there's any kind of link.

Comment: Given a set $X$ there might be a metric on it and also a measure on it.  What you really want to ask is what kind of *connection* should there be between the metric and measure in order for a property of $X$ from one viewpoint to influence a property from the other.  Boundedness might well  play a role, but Mr Idrissi points out that if your *connection* is invariant to the choice of equivalent metric, then boundedness would not be an interesting place to look